# PyQt5 - Signals&Slots - How to enable a button through content change of lineEdit?

Tags: button, signals-slots, pyqt5, qlineedit

since there isn't any useful How-To for beginners of PyQt5, I'm stuck with a little problem about signals & slots.

I do have a lineEdit which will get a directory path by a dialog (which works fine).
If one starts the program this lineEdit is empty by default and that's ok. A button, which shall generate a file list and show it in a list view, exists. It's functionality is implemented already and working fine. This button by default is disabled when the program is started for the first time.

What I want to do now is, enabling the button when something is entered at the lineEdit and disabling it when the content is removed.

I gave it a shot with this:

```
self.lineEdit_SelectedDirectory.editingFinished.connect(self.pushButton_CreateFileList.setEnabled)
```

but I get the error that it has not enough arguments, which might be clear because there aren't any provided in this code line.

Again, this was just a guess. How would one do this?

I would love something which takes the content into account like that, that it decides whether the content is empty or not and than sets the appropriate value to the button.

thx in advance for the help.

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want the [textChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#text-prop) signal, since that sends the current text:

```
    self.lineEdit_SelectedDirectory.textChanged.connect(
        lambda text: self.pushButton_CreateFileList.setEnabled(bool(text)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that does the trick. Using the lambda function generates the values needed to be interpreted as on/off switch.
I should go back and refresh my memories about the lambda function.